# "daesh" and not "islamic state"

Tags: discussion, tags

[Here,](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11868/how-can-daesh-acquire-these-modern-weapons) I asked a question with tag "Daesh".  *Philipp* changed the tag to  "islamic-state". He says in the comment "When you feel that the tag should be called "daesh" and not "islamic state", please start a thread on meta and request a tag rename." This I do:
The reasons that I think it should be called "daesh":
1- It is *proper noun*. proper nouns need not to be translated.
2- Philipp's answer to [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9333/why-does-obama-say-isil-instead-of-is-or-isis-or-islamic-state/9454#9454) has: "The argument that calling the terrorist organization "Islamic State" might be perceived as offensive ...". Although "daesh" means "islamic-state", but translating it may considered as Recognition of the word.

Answer (score 3):

I feel quoted out of context here. You might want to read [my complete answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/9348/3135) regarding the middle-east terrorist organization naming controversy.

> The argument that calling the terrorist organization "Islamic State" might be perceived as offensive because it implies they represent all of islam is comprehensible, but **that's how the group currently calls itself** and they really seem to believe that they represent all of islam (and those who disagree with them are [not "true" muslims, in their opinion](http://www.logicalfallacies.info/presumption/no-true-scotsman/), so they don't count). The alternative to using their self-given name would be to make up some new term for them like EPISMEE (Evil People in Iraq, Syria and other countries in the Middle East and now even in Europe), but good luck getting that to catch on.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to make the tag [daesh](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daesh) with [islamic-state](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-state) a synonym for it.   Note that I agree with @Philipp that the way to do this is via meta action rather than adding a second tag with an identical meaning.

1. Most English speakers won't know what Daesh actually means.  Normally I wouldn't find that an advantage, but in this case, people (Muslims) really do find it offensive to have to carry around the actions of this other organization that they believe perverts their religious teachings for its own aggrandizement.
2. It's perfectly clear to Arabic speakers.
3. It doesn't conflict with less controversial meanings of Islamic state, e.g. a country that is devoted to Islam.
4. It avoids the whole ISIS/ISIL argument.  I find this annoying as the Levant is a much bigger region than Syria.
5. If someone starts typing islamic-state as a tag, making it a synonym will still produce the correct tag.

There are four common names for the organization:  ISIS; ISIL; Islamic State; Daesh.  At the very least, I think that one of [islamic-state](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-state) and [daesh](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daesh) should be a synonym of the other.  I would prefer that [islamic-state](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-state) be a synonym for [daesh](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daesh).  That would require a moderator to implement, as questions are generally tagged the other way.